# Resolve message from property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can we resolve a message from properties file? Just like when we use

```
errors.reject ( "xyz.abc" );
```

in this case "xyz.abc" is resolved from the property file specified in messageResource ( servlet.xml )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement the [`MessageSourceAware`](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/context/MessageSourceAware.html) interface in your class. Something like this should do the trick.

```
public class Foo implements MessageSourceAware {

    protected MessageSource messageSource;

    ...

    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    ...

    public String bar(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
        return messageSource.getMessage("xyz.abc", 
                new Object[] { "arg1", "arg2" }, 
                RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request));
    }
}
```

Comment: do we have to write any bean definition in the applicationContext.xml file ?

Answer (score 1):

Just implement org.springframework.context.MessageSourceAware